# Multiple Autocomplete MUI show the selections but does not give a value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

`Autocomplete` Component:

```
      <Autocomplete
        filterSelectedOptions
        multiple
        size="small"
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Select Event" />
        )}
        value={this.state.confevents.find(
          (obj) => obj.value === this.state.selectedValue
        )}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
        onChange={this.selectyearValue}
        options={this.state.confevents}
      />
```

`onChange` callback:

```js
  selectyearValue(e) {
    const value = Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((s) => s.value) : [];
    this.setState({
      selectYear: value,
      selectedValue: value,
      isLoading: true,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectyearValue(e) {` callback should be

```js
selectyearValue(e, value) {
```

`<Autocomplete />` props docs: [https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#:~:text=provided%20translations.-,onChange,-func](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=provided%20translations.-,onChange,-func)

Comment: still does not work`<Autocomplete filterSelectedOptions multiple size="small" renderInput={(params) => ( <TextField {...params} label="Select Event" /> )} value={this.state.confevents.find( (obj) => obj.value === this.state.selectedValue )} getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value} onChange={this.selectyearValue} options={this.state.confevents} />`

Comment: can you check this function one more time it returns empty array


`  selectyearValue(e, value) {
    value = Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((s) => s.value) : [];
    this.setState({
      selectYear: Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((s) => s.value) : [],
      selectedValue: value,
      isLoading: true,
    });
    console.log("selectYear", this.state.selectYear);
    console.log("selectedValue", this.state.selectedValue);
  }`